# Regular expression replace whitespaces outside quotes (any)

Tags: php, regex

Let's suppose I have this string:

```
this is a "test for stackoverflow", with 'single quotes too' and "combined 'quotes single and double'"
```

And I need to get:

```
thisisa"test for stackoverflow",with'single quotes too'and"combined 'quotes single and double'"
```

This was just an example, but quotes can be nested up to 3 levels (" str ' str " str " ' "), there may be also multiple lines. I need to get a RegEx to replace all the spaces outside quotes.

Comment: Don't use regex. You will go crazy trying to apply regex to this problem.

Comment: @nneonneo What can I use? I need few lines of code and performance.

Comment: Walk over the string, keep track of your nesting level, and output to a new string where you skip over spaces. Performance should be fine unless you are trying to parse 10MB+ strings (in which case you have a different problem).

Comment: Unless your input text comes with apostrophes pre-replaced you're going to want to stick with just double quotes.

Comment: @nneonneo not true! S-F can be applied to this simple regex problem.

Comment: @Unihedron: I didn't say it *couldn't* be done, only that it is likely to be simpler for your sanity to do it with a simple loop than a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex for this:

```
$s = <<< EOF
this is a "test for stackoverflow" , with 'single quotes too' and "combined 'quotes single and double'"
EOF;
echo preg_replace('/(?| *(".*?") *| *(\'.*?\') *)| +/s', '$1', $s);
```

#### OUTPUT:

> `thisisa"test for stackoverflow",with'single quotes too'and"combined 'quotes single and double'"`

Comment: And for multiple lines?

Comment: It worked for me. @anubhava could you explain to me what’s the meaning of that empty `?` at the first match? Thanks.

Comment: If you're asking about `(?|...)` then it is called a : **Non-capturing group, Note: Sub-patterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index**

Answer (score 0):

### Simple (*SKIP)(*F) magic!

Use the following regex:

```
/(?:"[^"]++"|'[^']++')(*SKIP)(*F)|\s/
```

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/eD8oH3/2)

**Expression explanation:**

- `(?:"[^"]++"|'[^']++')` Matches quotes and everything within the quotes.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` Skips the pointer to the next position and discard the match.
- `|` *OR* (The following will only be matched if the above alternative does not discard this already
- `\s` Whitespaces.

Comment: How can I add to this expression to remove new lines too?

Comment: @Xriuk What do you mean? `[^"]` and `[^']` matches new lines, and `\s` matches new lines as well.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most elegant solution but it's a start (single-apostrophes  that aren't meant as a quote aren't supported. Replace those before and replace them back later):

```
<?PHP
    $str = "this is a  \"test for stackoverflow\", with 'single quotes too' and \"combined 'quotes single and double'\"";

    $cleared = clearString($str);
    $solution = "thisisa\"test for stackoverflow\",with'single quotes too'and\"combined 'quotes single and double'\"";

    assert($cleared == $solution);

    function copyQuote($str, $until, $offset = 0)
    {
        $p = strpos($str, $until, $offset);

        if ($p !== FALSE)
            return substr($str, $offset, $p-$offset);
        else
            throw new Exception("Unclosed Quote Exception at position ".$offset);
    }

    function clearString($str)
    {
        $retVal = "";

        $len = strlen($str);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
        {
            if ($str[$i] == "\"" || $str[$i] == "'")
            {
                $quote = copyQuote($str, $str[$i], $i+1);
                $retVal .= $str[$i].$quote.$str[$i];
                $i += strlen($quote)+1;
            } else {
                // Skip whitespaces outside of quotes, add any other check you'd like to do here
                if ($str[$i] != " " && $str[$i] != "\t")
                {
                    $retVal .= $str[$i];
                }
            }
        }
        return $retVal;
    }
?>
```